# If string is something then value is null

Tags: javascript

In javascript how can I write a function that if string is 'Select client' then address and contact number fields should be null or blank. I have already this function that if client name is selected then address and contact number fields are entered automatically using the populator gem of rails.

```
 $('#client_id').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/fetch_client",
            type: "POST",
            data: "id="+$(this).attr('value'),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                $('#client_address').attr('value',data.client_address);
                $('#client_contact_number').attr('value',data.client_contact_number);

            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }

        });
  });
```

Can some one please help me as I am new to javascript?

Comment: I don't understand precisely what you're asking. You want to check a string against a particular value?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#client_id').change(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == "Select client") {
                $('#client_address').attr('value', "");
                $('#client_contact_number').attr('value', "");
       } else {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/fetch_client",
            type: "POST",
            data: "id="+$(this).attr('value'),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
                $('#client_address').attr('value',data.client_address);
                $('#client_contact_number').attr('value',data.client_contact_number);

            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }

        });
     }
  });
```

Comment: Actually the select client is a dropdown thing. When I click on the prompt message "Select Client" then the address and the contact number field should be blank. I have to pass null value to the error block.

Comment: The change method touches a drop downdown *thing*. Did this answer your question?

Comment: I wrote this code in the error block. Can you tell me if this is correct?                                   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // alert("error");
          $('#client_address').value = " ";  
          $('#client_contact_number').value = " ";
     }

Comment: it should be `$('#client_address').val("");` instead of `$('#client_address').value = " ";`